# web scraper last pagination with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

is it possible to print all the pages on the web, I have problems with pagination, it should print all pages on the web, but it only displays 9 pages, while on the web there are 24 pages,

I want to print all the pages until the last one, while in pagination there are only 9 lists, whereas on the web there are 24 pages

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def login():    
    print('test login')
    urls = "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=0"
    headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
    }

    respon = requests.get(urls, headers=headers)
    f = open('./re.html', 'w+')
    f.write(respon.text)
    f.close()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(respon.text, 'html5lib')

    page_item = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'pagination-link-container__09f24__13AN7'})
    total_page = len(page_item)

    print(len(page_item))

    return total_page 

def get_url(page):
    print('test url ...')
    params = {
        'start': page
    }

    respon = requests.get('https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=0', params=params)
    

    suop = BeautifulSoup(respon.text, 'html5lib')

    titles = suop.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'text__09f24__2tZKC text-color--black-regular__09f24__1QxyO text-align--left__09f24__3Drs0 text-weight--bold__09f24__WGVdT text-size--inherit__09f24__2rwpp'})

    urls = []
    for title in titles:
        url = title.find('a')['href']
        urls.append(url)

    return  urls


def run():
    total_page = login()

    total_urls = []
    for i in range(total_page):
        page = i + 1

        # print(page)
        urls =  get_url(page)
        total_urls += urls
    
    # print(total_urls)
    print(len(total_urls))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after browsing through the pagination links it is clear that you can adjust the url using the parameter at the end of the URL. After clicking through the links, here is what I found:

| Pagination Button | URL Header |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `start=0` |
| 2 | `start=20` |
| 3 | `start=40` |

The clear pattern is that the counter starts at 0 and increases by 20 for each page. Now, all you need to do is extract the maximum number of pages and then use a simple for loop to get your urls. Luckily, there is a little box that displays how many pages there are at the right end of the page next to the pagination window.

Here is my example. This code just prints out the URLs

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    #Base url
    url = "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA"
    
    #Just getting the soup from the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    
    #Extracting the maximum number of pages
    #I used a CSS selector but anything can be used to grab it
    
    selector = ".text-align--center__09f24__31irQ .text-align--left__09f24__3Drs0"
    num = soup.select(selector)[0].text #This gives the string "1 of 12"
    
    #Splitting the string to get just the maximum
    num = num.split("of ")[1]
    num = int(num) #Now num = 12
    
    #Using a for loop to count up and concat the value to the url:
    for i in range(0, num*20, 20):
        print(url + "&start=" + str(i))
```

And here is my output:

```
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=0
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=20
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=40
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=60
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=80
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=100
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=120
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=140
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=160
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=180
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=200
    https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=contractors&find_loc=St%20Francis%20Wood%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA&start=220
```